# /dev/uio0 char device node not showing up

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I try to instantiate a uio (driver/uio/uio_pdrv_genirq.c) char device
to catch some gpio interrupts in userspace.

Everyting seems to be 
setup correctly, /sys/class/uio/uio0/ appears and also /proc/interrupts
shows my interrupt registered.

However what I miss is the /dev/uio0 entry.

I stepped through driver/uio/uio.c:__uio_register_device() and 
device_create() does succeed, so I wonder why /dev/uio0 doesnt
appear. I cannot use mknod because the major number is dynamically
assigned by driver/uio/uio.c.

Is there some extra kernel config I need to enable so that /dev/uio0
automatically appears or am I missing something? I have not enabled CONFIG_DEVTEMPFS, is this needed so that /dev/uio0 appears automatically?

Comment: Have you used dts overlay to bring the `/sys/class/uio/uio0` up? Trying to use `uio_pdrv_genirq` on RPI0, but having no luck of creating the right dts overlay file...

Comment: You need to enable the driver but also specify which "compatible" tag to use. You do this via the cmdline option like:  uio_pdrv_genirq.of_id=generic-uio .  Then you can add "compatible = generic-uio" in the dtb and the driver is matched to the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mounting devtempfs or configuring the kernel to automaount 
devtempfs on /dev is the solution.